# create unique constraints per user

Tags: ruby, postgresql, database-design, unique-constraint, sequel

I am building a small app and at this point I am creating the database schema. I use PostgreSQL with [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) and I have the two migrations:

```
Sequel.migration do
    change do

        Sequel::Model.db.run 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"'

        create_table :user do
            String :id, :type => :uuid, :primary_key => true, :default => Sequel.function(:uuid_generate_v4)


            DateTime :created_at
            DateTime :updated_at


            index :id, :unique => true
        end
    end
end

Sequel.migration do
    change do

        Sequel::Model.db.run 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"'

        create_table :location do
            String :id, :type => :uuid, :primary_key => true, :default => Sequel.function(:uuid_generate_v4)

            foreign_key :user_id, :user, :type => :uuid


            String :name, :unique => true, :null => false # TODO: unique, per user
            Float :latitude, :null => false
            Float :longitude, :null => false


            DateTime :created_at
            DateTime :updated_at


            index :id, :unique => true
            full_text_index :name, :index_type => :gist
        end
    end
end
```

As you can see the `name` column on the `location` table is unique, but I am in doubt about it. Because I want to establish a unique constraint on the name, but per user, so a user can have only one location with the same name but in the entire table many users can have locations with the same name (the relation between user and location is a one to many).

I suppose my `unique` constraint added on the column will make column generally unique, so amongst all users the location name must be unique. If so, how do I create a constraint that makes the `name` unique on a per user basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the unique constraint over both columns:

```
UNIQUE (user_id, name)
```

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS)

> This specifies that the combination of values in the indicated columns
>   is unique across the whole table, though any one of the columns need
>   not be (and ordinarily isn't) unique.

But from the looks of it, you really want another table `user_location` than implements an n:m relation between locations and users - with a primary key on `(user_id, location_id)`.

And don't call the first table "user", that's [a reserved word in standard SQL and in Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and shouldn't be used as identifier.

Comment: I do not want a n:m relation, a user can have many locations, but a location (or many locations) cannot belong to many users. As for the reserved word, I know that is reserved, but this is not a SQL database (not a Microsoft SQL DB), and I was aware only for those DB this table name is reserved, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, I found a list of [reserved identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) too. It seems it is. Do you have a suggestion on what I could rename the table to?

Comment: [SQL is the structured query language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) and has nothing to do with MS, they just use the term in their product like others do, too. I added a link for reserved words in Postgres above. You still *can* use "user", but then you have to double-quote it. Always. And that is error-prone. Name it "usr" or "users" or anything else.

Comment: I know that SQL is a language, but there are certain specific aspects of it depending on the database used. I found the same link too and I checked my other table's names for any reserved words and I found a few :) Thanks for pointing it out, I would have never discovered it ...

Comment: You may be interested in [this chapter of the manual about identifiers, too.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: what if I had two other tables (user and role tables) but with an n:m relation. Than the unique constraint could not be `UINQUE (user_id, name)` inside the `role` table because the `user_id` is not in that table but in a join table (role_user) that contains the `user_id` and the `role_id`. How would I add the unique constraint in this case?

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question with the necessary details. You can always link to this one for context.