# create unique constraints per user in tables with n:m relation

Tags: ruby, postgresql, database-design, unique-constraint, sequel

I have asked a question a few moments ago, [create unique constraints per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933811/create-unique-constraints-per-user) and the answer was very simple.

For creating a unique index on a column, but on a per user basis, all I have to do is:

```
unique [:user_id, :name] # SQL syntax: UNIQUE (user_id, name)
```

But the relation between the user table and the table that references the `user_id` is a 1:n (user to location), so I have a `foreign_key` inside the `location` table which references `user_id`. This question is about a n:m relation between two tables and adding a unique constraint on one of the tables.

```
Sequel.migration do
    change do

        Sequel::Model.db.run 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"'

        create_table :customer do
            String :id, :type => :uuid, :primary_key => true, :default => Sequel.function(:uuid_generate_v4)


            DateTime :created_at
            DateTime :updated_at


            index :id, :unique => true
        end
    end
end

Sequel.migration do
    change do

        Sequel::Model.db.run 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"'

        create_table :role do
            String :id, :type => :uuid, :primary_key => true, :default => Sequel.function(:uuid_generate_v4)


            String :name, :unique => true, :null => false # TODO: unique, per customer


            DateTime :created_at
            DateTime :updated_at


            unique [:customer_id, :name]

            index :id, :unique => true
            full_text_index :name, :index_type => :gist
        end
    end
end
```

The above code illustrates the two tables I mentioned have a n:m relation (customer to role), the following table illustrates the join table with the foreign keys for both the tables:

```
Sequel.migration do
    change do

        Sequel::Model.db.run 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"'

        create_table :customer_role do
            String :id, :type => :uuid, :primary_key => true, :default => Sequel.function(:uuid_generate_v4)

            foreign_key :customer_id, :customer, :type => :uuid
            foreign_key :role_id, :role, :type => :uuid

            index :id, :unique => true
        end
    end
end
```

What I would like to do is to declare a unique constraint such as `UNIQUE (customer_id, :name)` on the `role` table. But I cannot do that, so how do I achieve that in another way?

Comment: I think if you can remove  Id column of Role table and have a composite primary key on  {customer_id + role_id}, you will have the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I would like to do is to declare a unique constraint such as
>   UNIQUE (customer_id, :name) on the role table. But I cannot do that,
>   so how do I achieve that in another way?

The essence of your problem seems to be that the column role.customer_id doesn't exist. In fact, I'm pretty sure that column *shouldn't* exist, so that part's actually good.

At the very least, you need

```
unique [:customer_id, :role_id]
```

in "customer_role".

Comment: You are right Mike, I realised that at a later point, that I only needed a unique constraint on the `customer_role` join table.